# Sometimes Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership does not produce results

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
$UserInfo = Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq $email } -properties mail, title, manager, SamAccountName, distinguishedName | Select-Object SamAccountName, distinguishedName, title, manager

$UserSam = $UserInfo.SamAccountName

$ADGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $UserSam | Select-Object distinguishedName, name | Where-Object { ($_.distinguishedName -ne 'CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=Corp,DC=Domain,DC=com') -and ($_.distinguishedName -ne 'CN=Google-Users,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=com') }
```

I visually confirm the user has AD groups besides the two and the samaccountname is right. There is no error except that $ADGroups is empty. The odd thing is sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the domain is not syncing correctly. The command I am running is correct as far as I can tell.